# Calling a vim plugin command :Foo automatically does redraw! afterwards (that is performs :Foo | redraw!)

Tags: vim, plugins

I use the DirDiff plugin which is invoked using the command `:DirDiff <dir1> <dir2>`

However, whenever I invoke this command, the screen doesn't redraw properly so I've to manually do `redraw!` afterwards. Is there a way to wrap calls to the `DirDiff` command in my vimrc such that invoking it automatically does a `redraw!` afterwards. In essence it would look something like this: 
`map :DirDiff :DirDiff | redraw!`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use something like:

```
command Ddiff :DirDiff | redraw!
```

Now you have a new command Ddiff